# shell programming or SED / AWK

Tags: linux

I want to search all the ksh scripts present from  root directory and take out the directory path and check whether that directory is created /exists or not? this is the sample ksh script? Please help on this?

```
cd /home/edwprod/cormis/bin
if [ -f /home/edwprod/cormis/bin/churn.txt ]
then
echo " data not loaded in the table"
exit 0
else
cd /home/edwprod/edw/cfg
echo "XFB process is about to start"
/home/edwprod/edw/cfg/AUTOMATE_XFB_ADVISOR.ksh
fi
/osmf/mgmt/scheduler/edw/ROMEO/bin >cat EDWADVCHR.ksh
if [ -f /home/edwprod/cormis/bin/churn.txt ]
then
        cd /home/edwprod/cormis/bin/
        rm -f churn.txt
fi
/home/edwprod/cormis/bin/edw_etl_adv_churn_error.ksh CO_POP_ADVSR_DSCN_CHURN_I P
```

Comment: Your question makes no sense. If you have a list of ksh files from a root directory, of course their directory exists - how could the files exist otherwise? Please try and explain better. Also, what does that script have to do with your question?

Comment: May be some of the directory missed out. For example /home/edwprod/cormis/bin this directory is created but missed out creating /home/edwprod/cormis/log or /home/edwprod/edw/cfg. Only when executing this script i will come to know two directory missed. Did I make sense ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example script that tests if a list of directories exists or not.
It will print out the names of the missing directories, and exit with a non-zero return code if one of them is missing.

```
#! /bin/sh
dirs_to_check="/home/edwprod/cormis/bin
               /home/edwprod/cormis/log
               /home/edwprod/edw/cfg"

ok=1
for dir in $dirs_to_check ; do
    if [ ! -d $dir ] ; then
        echo "Directory $dir does not exist"
        ok=0
    fi
done

if [ $ok -ne 1 ] ; then
    exit 1
fi
```

You could fix this script to create the missing directories if you want.

It's not really necessary though. You could just adapt what you have and check that `cd` worked:

```
cd /some/path
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
  # you failed to cd: either the directory doesn't exist, 
  # or you have permission issues
fi
```